# Realtek ALC1200 Sound input

Tags: 10.04, sound, alsa, realtek, input

i'm using Realtek audio card in MSI GX620 Laptop

```
$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC1200
Codec: Motorola Si3054
Codec: Nvidia MCP78 HDMI

$ uname -a
Linux machine 2.6.32-31-generic-pae #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 20:00:13 UTC 2011 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

Unfortunately i cannot catch any microphone true input. USB ones work perfectly. Internal one too.

Anny suggestions?

I've tried GNOME alsa mixer. No luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've succeed! I' just needed to mess around with:

```
$ alsamixer -c 0
```